# css - what could cause the difference in this WP page styling?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have created two identical versions of this wordpress site from scratch, but on the homepage featured items on the second site, the content is moved up over the upper border twenty or so pixels.

http://jdrig.netii.net/

http://s502809412.onlinehome.us/

Both are manually coded html and css. I copied and pasted the styling and page content from one site to the other exactly, so I can't think of what the issue could be. Where could I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove that p tag in this html of your 1 url  http://jdrig.netii.net/

```
<div id="feat-item-1" class="feat-item">
        <a href="http://jdrig.netii.net/products/"><p></p>
```